# Append line on every input value in textarea separated by comma jQuery (Code Optimisation Need)

Tags: jquery

I have made a code which can append line depending on textarea values separated by comma. But problem is that I need to add every line of code again and again to append new lines. If I want to append 100 or 200 lines with the code then it would be not possible to use this code. I want to optimize this code so that I don't need to repeat same line of code again and again. I need some code in which I just keep writing or deleting values in textarea and accordingly it append or remove as many as lines from div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.match').bind("change keyup input", function() {
    var aux = $('.match').val().split(',');
    $('.peak').remove();
    $('.matchi').append("<div class='peak' style='left:" + aux[0] + "%'>" + aux[0] + "</div>").append("<div class='peak' style='left:" + aux[1] + "%'>" + aux[1] + "</div>").append("<div class='peak' style='left:" + aux[2] + "%'>" + aux[2] + "</div>").append("<div class='peak' style='left:" + aux[3] + "%'>" + aux[3] + "</div>")
  });
});
```

```css
.peak {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.5%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<textarea class='match'>
20, 45, 60, 85, 95
</textarea>
<div class='matchi' style='position:relative;background:#eee;padding-top:18%' />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just regenerate the whole thing each `input` event. Also, you can `trigger` that input on doc.ready to get started.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.match').on('input', updateMatch)
  $('.match').trigger('input')
});

function updateMatch() {
  $('.matchi').html($(this).val().split(',').map(e => `<div class='peak' style='left:${e.trim()}%'>${e.trim()}</div>`).join(''));
}
```

```css
.peak {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.5%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='match'>
20, 45, 60, 85, 95
</textarea>
<div class='matchi' style='position:relative;background:#eee;padding-top:18%' />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable reply sir, Can you please help me in one thing. Actually with every line I want to add some extra text from another textarea. For example, in another textarea I will write peak-123, peak-342, peak-421, peak232, peak748. And I want to add peak-123 in 20, peak-342 in 45, peak-421 in 60 and so on. Please help sir if possible.

Comment: You'll have to update your question, or better yet, since this one is solved, go ahead and open a new question with this new intel.